# Dúvida sobre chat em aplicação Web com Java e PrimeFaces

Tags: javascript, java, primefaces

Bom gostaria de tirar uma dúvida. Tenho que fazer uma espécie de *chat* onde as pessoas possam conversar entre si. Ele irá funcionar igual a um *chat* de `Facebook` ou `WhatsApp` por exemplo, porém não possuo nenhuma base ou referência que eu possa pesquisar. Isso irá para uma aplicação *Web* feita com Java.

É possível fazer isso, por exemplo, com `PrimeFaces` ou `JavaScript`? Poderiam me passar alguns links onde posso pesquisar isso?

Answer (score 5):

É possível fazer de acordo com algumas tecnologias ou serviços de comunicação assíncrona, como:

- [WebSocket](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455)

Esta, por sua vez, está disponível na especificação JSR 356 do Java EE (tal especificação pode ser executada em Web containers também, por exemplo, o Tomcat e Jetty), JavaScript e outras linguagens também implementam WebSockets, segue um exemplo básico:

**Servidor**

```
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/chat/{sala}")
public class ChatEndpoint {
    private final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());

    @OnOpen
    public void open(final Session session, @PathParam("sala") final String sala)   {
      log.info("Sessão aberta para sala: " + sala);
      session.getUserProperties().put("sala", sala);
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(final Session session, final String mensagem) {
      String sala= (String) session.getUserProperties().get("sala");
      try {
        for (Session s : session.getOpenSessions()) {
            if (s.isOpen()
                    && sala.equals(s.getUserProperties().get("sala"))) {
                s.getBasicRemote().sendText(mensagem);
            }
        }
      } catch (IOException | EncodeException ex) {
        log.log(Level.WARNING, "onMessage falhou", ex);
      }
    }
}
```

**Cliente JavaScript**

```
<script>
    var wSocket = new WebSocket("ws://hostname:8080/chat/sala3");
    var browserSupport = ("WebSocket" in window);

    function initializeReception() {
        if (browserSupport) {
            wSocket.onopen = function () {};
        }            
    }

    function enviar(mensagem) {
        wSocket.send(mensagem)
    }

    wSocket.onmessage = function (event) {
        var mensagemRecebida = event.data;
        console.log(mensagemRecebida);
    };

    wSocket.onclose = function () {};
</script>
```

Alguns links úteis:

http://www.hascode.com/2013/08/creating-a-chat-application-using-java-ee-7-websockets-and-glassfish-4/

https://tyrus.java.net/ *Implementação de referência no Java EE*

http://javaeesquad.blogspot.com.br/2014/05/chat-application-in-java-ee-7.html

Answer (score 0):

Só dando uma complementada de uma olhada no Chat que o Primefaces tem no showcase deles, segue o [link](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/chat.xhtml), quem sabe pode te ajudar.